# How to get headers from a csv file after putting conditions

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am looking for a way to get the column name of files after putting condition in rows of CSV.

I am getting the desired output , but not getting the column names, I have to get the output in excel with the column names or row headers.

```
include_cols = ['TICKETID', 'TICKETNAME', 'TICKETSENTDATE', 
                'TICKETREQUESTER', 'TICKETCATEGORYNAME',
                'TICKETLOCATION', 'SERVICEGROUPNAME', 
                'SERVICETYPENAME', 'SERVICESTATENAME', 'REACTIONTIME', 
                'SOLUTIONTIME']

search_for = ['Resolved','Closed','Rejected']

with open(files3, "rt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if '+' in row['SOLUTIONTIME'] and row['SERVICESTATENAME'] not in search_for:
            content = list(row[i] for i in include_cols)
            print(content)
```

Comment: Your `include_cols` are the **headers**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not load the csv into a pandas dataframe using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html ? That would make it much easier to retrieve the name of the column.

Comment: You should add the commands used to import as csv file and read it.

`import pandas as pd
csv_file = pd.read_csv(FILENMAE)
csv_headers = csv_file.columns.values
`